# A large number of windows problems when using the MVP pattern

Tags: oop, mvp

**The situation:** Suppose we have a project in which two dozen different boxes with your business logic. Each window can cause other windows. Some windows MDI. Almost all the windows there are methods and setProgressOverlay showMessage. However, not all!
*Immediately comes to mind is the creation of a large nesting hierarchy of different types of twist.*

**Actually the question:** how to work with many different ideas as to open other windows (closing) of the presenter.

Answer (score 1):

Write a window manager service to handle the new windows.

You may use different levels for windows (normal/modal).

Whenever you need to open a window, you ask the window manager to do it.

For example, if there is a modal window displayed, any new requests for opening windows gets denied by the window manager.